# How to make dask dataframe read from stdin?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science, dask, dask-dataframe

For dask dataframe I want to give `sys.stdin` as input

```
dask.dataframe.read_csv(sys.stdin, sep=" ", header=None)
```

But, dask.dataframe only accepts file path/paths as input, so it gives an error.
Is there a way to read from stdin with dask without having to save the whole stdin to a file ?

Here, the contents of a very large file are being piped to a python program as input.

Answer (score 1):

The value-added of `dask` in this case is not clear, since presumably `stdin` is small enough to fit into memory (if it's not, then it's interesting why the data is not persisted). In any case, here's one possible workflow:

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, sep=" ", header=None)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10) # adjust as appropriate
```

Comment: what if stdin is very large ? since i am piping the contents of a large file to a python program as input

Comment: In that case you really want a library for streaming data, take a look at streamz: https://streamz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataframes.html

Comment: oops, your comment was edited so my previous comment is for streaming data. if your data is in a file, then it's best to avoid stdin as intermediary and read from the file directly (with dask).

Comment: But in case if the input file is piped, how to make dask read from stdin? can you please give an example.

Comment: Well, if the data is in a file, why not pass the file directly to dask (not via stdin)? so something like `dd.read_csv(path_to_file, ...) # ... add options as appropriate`.